# getModel is not a function

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'm trying to get my model from view with model name, but I'm getting this error.

in base controller

```
var view = new sap.ui.view({id: "myView",viewName: "iddesign.MainPg",type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS});
        view.setModel(oJson,"myModel");
```

in view

```
   var model = this.getModel("myModel");
        var oFraction=0;
        if(model != undefined)
        {
        for (i=0; i<model.getProperty("/d/results/").length;i++)
        {
            oFraction += Number(model.getProperty("/d/results/"+[i]+"/Dialog"));
        }
        oFraction /= oJson.getProperty("/d/results/").length;   
        oMicroChart.setFraction(oFraction)
        //console.log(oPercentage);
        oText.setText("Average Dialog = " + oFraction);
        }
```

"MainPg.view.js?eval:87 Uncaught TypeError: this.getModel is not a function"
My SapUi5 version is 1.44.13.

Actualy I'm trying to bind my model manualy in to the micro chart with the code above.

When I try this without name it works just fine but dont get the model I want.

Comment: where is this code placed in view? in createContent method of it? and in any case, i think you should use your controller for model binding.

Comment: agree with the previous orator, your coding looks very chaotic and breaks all best practices :) Have you tried using XML view and data binding? I'd recommend you to go through the tutorials from official ui5 site.

Comment: Yes I am writing it in createcontent, its a bit of weird but I just want it to work. Now I made that possible with getCore().getModel() but I'm wondering what I was doing wrong. Thanks for your reply guys. Also I'm trying to bind my data manualy like get some variables average value. Do you know anything about it? What should I search for that. Can I do that in xmlview too? Thanks again.

Comment: it means `this` is not what you think it is, in the place this code is used. if it's in the view, `this` might mean the view object not the controller object. `console.log(this)` might tell you what it is

Comment: I got this just because of I was writing it in interval function and as you sad this was not mean view (I'll write my question more clear next time). Thanks all.